# page refresh after remove of hash bang using ui-router is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to ui-router.

I have written the states as follows:

```
angularApp.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider","$locationProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

'use strict';

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/page1");
$stateProvider.state('page1', {
    url: '/page1',
    templateUrl: '../Scripts/angular/views/page1.html',
    controller: ''
})
.state('page2', {
    url: '/page2',
    templateUrl: '../Scripts/angular/views/page2.html',
    controller: 'page2Ctrl',
})
}]);
```

By using html5Mode and hashPrefix I remove #!

if I have url as http://localhost:54321/#!/page1, it display as http://localhost:54321/page1

But when I refresh the page as there is no page1, it gives an error on server side.
Is there any way to handle this scenario, where when I refresh the page I need to check that url which contains page1 and redirect to 
http://localhost:54321/#!/page1, so that ui-router will remove #!

Is it really possible? If not please suggest me any possible solution

Comment: *if I have url as http://localhost:54321/#!/page1, it display as http://localhost:54321/page1* what it means? are you able to see both URL

Comment: It means, if I provide url as http://localhost:54321/#!/page1, as it triggers ui-router, it will display as http://localhost:54321/page1

Comment: I think you need to write `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` only and that is after the all `.state` declrations. and write `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');` if you require that this page should open on page load

Comment: As I need to remove #! I have to use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!'); What ever you said wont work. After I had this url http://localhost:54321/page1, Once I refresh the page server side error will trigger, as there is no such controller on server side, but I want to restrict before calling server controller

Comment: use `resolve` property than

Comment: if i know how to use that, i would have resolve the problem, please provide me jsfiddle

Comment: create basic fiddle first, I'll try to modify according to the requirement.